# Achievement drop-down shows a strange icon

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

I was on the chat.SE homepage today and I clicked the `+5` that appeared.

[image: wtf1]

Hold on...

[image: wtf2]

What is that icon and why is it there? To clarify, the achievement was gained on PPCG.SE.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What browser (version)? What OS? Did you disable extensions and retry? Hard refresh? Any errors on the console?

Comment: @Oded nvm, turns out it was a bug with a userscript I have, not SE itself. [tag:status-norepro]